# Convert multi-line ssh public key to one-line for .ssh/authorized_keys

Tags: ssh

I received a public key like this and I should add it to .ssh/authorized_keys:

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "rsa-key-20190107"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAucNIPbPoaEqyBAKtk3LTfM/hiZlWomTdQEf7
zUI4LGz91aZYIZNpWGTAUZKuFLdIEsktxQTNwEJNWMe2QocqQWyPGA+xL08ZP7Xk
VEbVOyH0nQ3ZHptgmyH4y4+bbAWXAROL3078h2iwtsCO343VQKg1iSNvemnLafA5
9/RtkcCR8SxH+NEXcc8MwGOE9gLX2pph4bxrFz9R6yyw3oRGVLt4uU9BlD3+LXg1
plUzc2KZXEt8Zr04I0Fd865zyiB8Q+2ZEPvHf7MMaW66FRe4BXCI7LMh/voXi0C8
H4NDIu1GZr7dNxgbEO05ZnASMofpLDU6cq7LFVl0BQG8gt1hOw==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

I guess that I can edit this file in `vi` and to create the corresponding one-liner which is required for .ssh/authorized_keys.

Is this true?

AFAIK this key was created according to this page: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_public_key

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can use a text editor to create the matching line, or your can use this command line:

```
ssh-keygen -i -f tmp/Public-Key
```

Result:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAucNIPbPoaEqyBAKtk3LTfM/hiZlWomTdQEf7zUI4LGz91aZYIZNpWGTAUZKuFLdIEsktxQTNwEJNWMe2QocqQWyPGA+xL08ZP7XkVEbVOyH0nQ3ZHptgmyH4y4+bbAWXAROL3078h2iwtsCO343VQKg1iSNvemnLafA59/RtkcCR8SxH+NEXcc8MwGOE9gLX2pph4bxrFz9R6yyw3oRGVLt4uU9BlD3+LXg1plUzc2KZXEt8Zr04I0Fd865zyiB8Q+2ZEPvHf7MMaW66FRe4BXCI7LMh/voXi0C8H4NDIu1GZr7dNxgbEO05ZnASMofpLDU6cq7LFVl0BQG8gt1hOw==
```

This works, too:

```
puttygen -O public-openssh tmp/Public-Key
```